# Need a way to transform XML to HTML chunk by chunk using SAXParser

Tags: java, xml, xslt, saxparser

I have an XML file of size 130 MB. I am trying the read the xml file chunk by chunk which I was able to do. I need a way to transform this chunk to HTML using xslt parser.

I am trying to implement in the same way that is mentioned in "http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/"

Here they have given an example on how to get xml chunk by chunk. But not provided any information on how to transform this chunk to HTML.
Can anybody provide me a snippet/suggestions using the same example provided in the above link.

Comment: Do you want to create several HTML documents, one for each chunk? Which XSLT processor do you want to use? With Java there is the option of using Saxon 9 which does XSLT 2.0 and 3.0 by now.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I want to create single HTML. If we consider the example attached in the link there are two xml entries for the staff tag(two chunks), for this my result.HTML should generate two rows one for each staff details. I am ok with any JAVA xslt processor which is open source or free.

Comment: What do you need help with, writing the XSLT code to transform that XML input to HTML with a table and two rows, writing the Java code to run the XSLT, or both?

Comment: @MartinHonnen I need help in writing the JAVA code after reading xml to parse to XSLT transformer.

Comment: Well try a tutorial like http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/excerpt/java_xslt_ch5/?page=4 which explains the JAXP XSLT API. Whether you want to use a `StreamSource` or `SAXSource` does not really matter, the XSLT processor will build its tree model anyway.